# On Potential interpolations in The Vedas as per Matsya Purana

Tags: vedas, puranas, interpolation, matsya-purana

The Following is what I came across while reading [Matsya Purana Chapter 144.](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45858/page/n54/mode/1up?view=theater)

> Before, There was Only Veda having four feet(parts). That Got changed
> on and on, due to the short lives of the people, until at last in
> Dvapara, the one veda was abridged and divided in four Vedas.**The sons
> of the Risis, again due to their respective faulty understandings
> explained them in various ways.They inserted the Brahmana Portions
> within the samhita portions of the Rik,Yajuh and Sama vedas. They even
> changed the Svaras or musical tones in the songs of the Vedas**. They did
> not fully grasp the meanings partly owing to their habits and faulty
> understandings, **and partly owing to many corruptions and
> interpolations in the Vedas, of the Brahmana portions, of the Kalpa
> sutras,of the Bhasyas and various other things**. Some parts were
> correctly explained. It is in this Dvaparayuga that persons adopted
> various customs and rites and began to hold different opinions.
>
> At first the Advharyu's work was one.Afterwords, it was divided into
> two.**Owing to distortions and twistings in the meanings, the Sastras
> have much transformed.Therefore, the Adhvaryu's works are performed in
> different ways.The Sama and Atharva vedas also were turned and twisted
> owing to the want of knowledge of the munis and their want of
> confidence.** Thus the state of things in the Dvapara age was in a
> chaotic condition. And in the Kaliyuga the vedas became extinct.

Is All this this really true? That Brahmana,Kalpasutra etc. portions have been inserted in the Vedas by later rishis and their Svaras etc. have been changed?

Comment: All of it is naturally true. Have you read a Braahmana or Aaranyaka or Upanishat? They're all obviously written by a human (or rather, Rshi). As for later interpolations into Braahmanas, it's a possibility as they deal with the 'how'of the Veda. Check the pronunciation of Veda Mantras in various parts of India, let alone Swaras, even the pronunciation of श ष स are mixed up (among many other errors) in most parts of the north and east. And, I'm only commenting about those regions as I've personally heard them. There's no reason to assume something more subtle (Svaras) wouldn't be changed.

Comment: "They inserted the Brahmana Portions within the samhita portions of the Rik,Yajuh and Sama vedas..." - these verses are not talking about any interpolation or errors. They are talking about misarrangement of vedas into books or chapters eg: taittiriya where samhita and brahmana portions are mixed up, etc.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar last part :And in the Kaliyuga the vedas became extinct.       , :so this is interpolation in puran not in vedas.

Comment: the word 'interpolations', etc. isn't used, the translation you're reading is actually quite erroneous. The translator is putting his own biases, and messing up the translation of the actual Sanskrit ślokas. *The Brāhmaṇa portions are changed*, it refers to the commentaries and/or the divisions of Brāhmaṇas into bhāgas, and the different arrangements, not actual Brāhmaṇas being 'interpolated' as such, as @ekAntika pointed out too. As for kalpsūtras, they are compositions of Ṛṣis to begin with, but the comms. determine their interpretations. Different 'schools' would interpret them differently.

Comment: @Hope There's no interpolation in the actual Veda Samhitaa. At most, the pronunciation may have (and indeed certainly has in many parts of India) deviated. This has also happened to Puranas in a larger way in the form of 'Paatha Bheda' where similar meanings are conveyed with differing words in different Purana manuscripts. As for Brahmanas, the 'interpolation' itself is done by later Rshis/Shrotriyas, it's not something that's done maliciously to change the meaning (which is what Purana interpolation theory claims), but, at most due to misunderstandings. This translation is *slightly* faulty.